# Can't delete unwanted favicon

Tags: server, options, favicon, customization

I have a favicon that is a remnant of a disactivated wordpress theme.  I can't find the favicon file in the theme folder, or the wordpress or server root.

I have added my own reference to a new favicon, but the old one is still displayed.

> <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://www.steve.doig.com.au/wordpress/wp-content/themes/grid-focus-public-10/images/favicon.ico">

My site is [here](http://www.steve.doig.com.au/wordpress/).

**Edit:** Favicon is [New Favicon http://www.steve.doig.com.au/wordpress/wp-content/themes/grid-focus-public-10/images/favicon.ico](http://www.steve.doig.com.au/wordpress/wp-content/themes/grid-focus-public-10/images/favicon.ico)

Comment: I see your in Aus like me!

Comment: if your mime type is PNG .... then do not specify an ICO..

Comment: We just discussed much of the favicon topic in wordpress, probably you'll find an answer to your question in [How to change the WordPress favicon?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9347/how-to-change-the-wordpress-favicon/)

Comment: I've produced a new PNG image, uploaded it, and repointed the header link to it, but I can't see it yet (although the old icon is gone).  Have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default favicon location on your server gives a 404:

> http://www.steve.doig.com.au/favicon.ico

Your [blogs homepage](http://www.steve.doig.com.au/wordpress/) source-code related to linking to another location is:

> <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://www.steve.doig.com.au/wordpress/wp-content/themes/grid-focus-public-10/images/favicon.ico">

**Note:** The file suffix is .ico which normally stands for an Microsoft Icon file. But names are not interesting for that. The `type="image/png"` is correct here, it's a PNG file.

Your blogs server does return the following mime-type header for that linked favicon:

> Content-Type: image/x-icon

**Note:** That information is wrong. The file's mime content type is acutally `ìmage/png`. Please reconfigure your server, rename the file to .png or convert the image in that file into the `image/x-icon` type (you can choose only one of these three options, the last one is the one I would do).

### Suggestions

1. Use a program that is able to properly save the microsoft ico file-format. Don't use a PNG, use a true ICO.
2. Place your favicon.ico file then into the root of your server.
3. Modify the links' href to the new location.
4. Delete any old favicon.ico files from your server, delete your browsers chache, it's history etc. . Then restart your computer. The old favicon should be gone next time you visit your page on that computer.

You'll find more details in [How to change the WordPress favicon?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9347/how-to-change-the-wordpress-favicon/)

Comment: After seeing this answer, I feel ashamed about mine :P Excelent job!

Answer (score 0):

I see an 'S' on a white background.

If you are still seeing the old favicon, it maybe your browser cache/history that is storing the image and matching it against the URL/domain.

Try looking on a different browser with an empty cache/history.

Comment: pushed submit at the same time as Fernando - didn't mean to repeat answer :)

Comment: Yeah, that happens pretty often, don't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing this favicon when entering the site:
http://www.steve.doig.com.au/wordpress/wp-content/themes/grid-focus-public-10/images/favicon.ico

[image]

Have you hard reloaded the website? Have you cleared the browser cache? Try looking at the site on a different browser.